# How to use InjectTouchInput for specific window?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm trying to use [InjectTouchInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802881%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to send touch events to specific window. [POINTER_INFO structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has `hwndTarget` field, which, as I understood, specifies target window to send input to.

But when I try to use this parameter, injection fails with code `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (87)`

Code:

```
void MakePointerTouchInfo(POINTER_TOUCH_INFO& contact, int x, int y, int radius, int id, int orientation = 90, int pressure = 32000)
{
ZeroMemory(&contact, sizeof(POINTER_TOUCH_INFO));
contact.pointerInfo.pointerType = PT_TOUCH;
contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x = x;
contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y = y;
contact.pointerInfo.pointerId = id;


contact.touchFlags = TOUCH_FLAG_NONE;
contact.pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_DOWN | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT;
contact.touchMask = TOUCH_MASK_NONE;
}

POINTER_TOUCH_INFO contacts[2];

// to start injection in separate thread.
DWORD makeInjection_(LPVOID p)
{
 InitializeTouchInjection(5, TOUCH_FEEDBACK_DEFAULT);

MakePointerTouchInfo(contacts[0], 200, 300, 2, 1);
MakePointerTouchInfo(contacts[1], 250, 300, 2, 6);

HWND hwnd = hWnd;

    // if I don't set hwnd (default 0), it works
contacts[0].pointerInfo.hwndTarget 
    = contacts[1].pointerInfo.hwndTarget 
    = hwnd;

if (!InjectTouchInput(1, contacts))
{
        //
        //here it fails
        //
        LPWSTR str = new wchar_t[255];
    auto t = GetLastError();
    wsprintf(str, L"%d\n", t);
    OutputDebugString(str);
}

contacts[0].pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_UPDATE | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT;
contacts[1].pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_UPDATE | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT;

//drag them from/to each other
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    contacts[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x += 1;
    contacts[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x -= 1;
    bool s = InjectTouchInput(1, contacts);
    Sleep(10);
}

//release them
contacts[0].pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_UPDATE;
contacts[1].pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_UPDATE;

bool success2 = InjectTouchInput(1, contacts);

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `hwndTarget` is *not* the window to which you send the input, it is an *output* field, which tells you which window had the input capture and/or was under the (x,y) position that you specified for the injected contact. As MSDN says:

[image: msdn]

The injected input is not sent to a specific window, but - again quoting [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802881(v=vs.85).aspx) - to the desktop:

> The injected input is sent to the desktop of the session where the
>   injection process is running.

Perhaps you need to explore the function [`RegisterPointerInputTarget`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454911(v=vs.85).aspx), which *"allows the caller to register a target window to which all pointer input of the specified type is redirected"*. However, you cannot do this to redirect input in all cases:

[image: msdn]

Comment: Strange thing is that `hwndTarget` remains zero after `InjectTouchInput` call, so it doesn't work as out parameter. Also `RegisterPointerInputTarget` is not exactly what I need, because I need to send input events to different application windows almost simultaneously. I'm looking at just sending events via `PostMessage` but hope there is more programmer friendly solution.