# Implement zoom functionality like touchpad

Tags: c#

I'm working on an app in which I'm going to map mouse functions onto keyboard keys. For example, if a user presses 'L', the app will simulate a left mouse click. I have already mapped clicks and scroll using:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);
```

Now I want to implement the zoom in and out functionality. Like in laptops, using pinch on the touchpad, we can zoom in and out. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice function in Windows 8+ - [InjectTouchInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802881(v=vs.85).aspx). It allows you to inject touch events or mouse events with any parameters you want. It also is packed into [.net wrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TCD.System.TouchInjection/).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288761/how-to-use-injecttouchinput-for-specific-window) already contains working C++ sample code for pinch, you can adapt it to your needs. This will simulate zoom by touchscreen.

This is one way. Other way may be by sending [WM_MOUSEWHEEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645617(v=vs.85).aspx) with CTRL key modifier to target HWND, basically simulating mouse wheel zoom.

Comment: _This is one way. Other way may be by sending WM_MOUSEWHEEL with CTRL key modifier to target HWND, basically simulating mouse wheel zoom._ I used this approach.